# Failed to execute user defined function RegexTokenizer in Pyspark

Tags: text, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to perform text classification using text feature in the data using Pyspark. Below is my code for text preprocessing and the code is giving failed to execute user defined function RegexTokenizer.

```
    tokenizer = RegexTokenizer(inputCol = "text", outputCol = "words", pattern = "\\W")
    add_stopwords = StopWordsRemover.loadDefaultStopWords("english")
    remover = StopWordsRemover(inputCol = "words", outputCol = "filtered").setStopWords(add_stopwords)
    label_stringIdx = StringIndexer(inputCol = "label", outputCol = "target")
    countVectors = CountVectorizer(inputCol="filtered", outputCol="features", vocabSize=1000, minDF=5)
    #pipleline for text pre-processing
    pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer,remover, countVectors, label_stringIdx])

    #fit the dat for the pipeline
    pipelineFit = pipeline.fit(dataset)
    dataset = pipelineFit.transform(dataset)
    dataset.show()
```

The Error is:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o589.fit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 92.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 92.0 (TID 1317, 1e1a151fa0f5, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(RegexTokenizer$$Lambda$3017/0x000000084123e040: (string) => array<string>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:489)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:444)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:447)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer.$anonfun$createTransformFunc$2(Tokenizer.scala:146)
    ... 19 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2023)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:1972)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1971)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1971)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:950)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:950)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:950)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2203)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2152)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2141)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:752)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2093)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2114)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2133)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2158)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1227)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer.fit(CountVectorizer.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer.fit(CountVectorizer.scala:149)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(RegexTokenizer$$Lambda$3017/0x000000084123e040: (string) => array<string>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:489)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:444)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:447)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer.$anonfun$createTransformFunc$2(Tokenizer.scala:146)
    ... 19 more
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is because you have `null` values in the input column `text`.

```scala
 val tokenizer = new RegexTokenizer()
      .setInputCol("text")
      .setOutputCol("words")
      .setPattern("\\W")

    val inputDF = Seq("this is text", null).toDF("text")
    inputDF.show(false)

    /**
      * +------------+
      * |text        |
      * +------------+
      * |this is text|
      * |null        |
      * +------------+
      */

    // this fails
    tokenizer.transform(inputDF)
      .show(false)

    /**
      * Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
      * at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$2.apply(Tokenizer.scala:143)
      * at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$2.apply(Tokenizer.scala:141)
      */
```

### Either remove null rows or impute null columns

```scala
    // replace nulls from text col to specified string as below
    val nullImputedDF = inputDF.na.fill("I am null imputed", Seq("text"))
    tokenizer.transform(nullImputedDF)
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +-----------------+----------------------+
      * |text             |words                 |
      * +-----------------+----------------------+
      * |this is text     |[this, is, text]      |
      * |I am null imputed|[i, am, null, imputed]|
      * +-----------------+----------------------+
      */
```

Comment: when I check for the null values in the data, it shows zero. this is my output: 
+-----+----+-------+----+------+
|title|text|subject|date|target|
+-----+----+-------+----+------+
|    0|   0|      0|   0|     0|
+-----+----+-------+----+------+ Also when I try to run the regextokenizer and stopwords remover, it works fine without error... but when i include count_vectorizer, I am facing this issue. Is this still because of the null values in text column? Please let me know.

Comment: Please Check your stacktrace once. It clearly says nullpointerexception `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer.$anonfun$createTransformFunc$2(Tokenizer.scala:146)
    ... 19 more`. I have demoed the same thing in my answer with the solution on that

Comment: got it ...I dropped the null values and it worked...thank you so much for your help!